# Top padding is not working on table when using border-collapse

Tags: css, padding

I have this CSS for a table inside a div:

```
#orderTabel {
padding-top: 30px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

But the padding has no effect. When I delete `border-collapse: collapse;`, it works but adds 30px to the top-border instead of 30px of empty space.
When I use `margin-top: 30px;`, it also works, but adds 30px to the entire div.

Comment: Is this fiddle anything like what you are experiencing? http://jsfiddle.net/hnb85rd0/ I added a 1px black border to the containing div for clarity

Comment: please provide some more information(`codes`) or any link to something like `jsfiddle`

Comment: @KyleT Yes, That's exactly  what I'm experiencing

Comment: @Bouss Have you had a look at my answer yet? If i understand correctly what you are trying to do then it should provide a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add an additional container for your `<table>` element between the outer container and style it to suit your needs?

**HTML**

```
<div class="border">
    <div class="top-margin">
        <table id="orderTabel">
            <tr><th> Head </th><th> Head </th><tr>
            <tr><td> addaa </td><td> addaa </td></tr>
            <tr><td> addaa </td><td> addaa </td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table, td, th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.border
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.top-margin
{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#orderTabel 
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnb85rd0/4/)

Hope this helps.